# Code Structuring for Custom View Classes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I apologize in advance that this is a somewhat vague topic/question.

Let's say I am coding the activity class for a common board game. This class can be named Game.java (generically enough) and extends Activity and maintains a few buttons and text views and (more importantly) a custom View class called Board.java (or a static nested class) that extends SurfaceView.

Now, all of the drawing is basically required to be done within the SurfaceView class, since that's the nature of Android applications. The question that presents itself is, if the pieces of this board game (e.g. - the heroes and monsters) are stored in relative lists, where does best practice dictate that those lists be stored? That is, one would think that these lists should be maintained by the Game class, since that is technically a more encompassing overall view of the game in progress. However, the static nested class (or separate top-level class) Board has no access to these lists in this case, and so for drawing purposes, it has no idea what the state of each piece is without it being maintained in both classes simultaneously, which is extremely cumbersome. Almost equally cumbersome is maintaining this list in Board, which seems to abstract the purpose of Game significantly aside from assigning it as an activity to be started.

Any overall consensus or opinions on how this could be cleanly implemented? My own personal thoughts lean towards maintaining it in Board, for memory and sanity purposes more than anything, but if there's a something obvious missing, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a little bit of experimentation with this and had success when my custom `SurfaceView` class contains a custom implementation of a `Thread`.  Along with handling all the physics and drawing, this thread has inner classes that represent the objects that get drawn and maintains lists of these objects for all visible items on my canvas.

Google includes samples when downloading the SDK, and they have a few that deal with drawing on a canvas.  I found the LunarLander sample to be a very good starting point for how to implement this behavior.  Once you've downloaded the samples with the SDK manager, you can find them in `android-sdk/samples`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I should have pointed out that the SurfaceView also implements Runnable so it is indeed a thread. My original way of coding all of this was the way you described, it just become cumbersome as the code developed to have to constantly access the Board object in Game. It feels like it takes away the utility of the Game object itself, aside from being a placeholder for the Activity and a couple buttons.